# lxml in appengine external namespaces

Tags: python, xslt, lxml

Is there a way to configure lxml to fetch external xsl templates in appengine?

I'm currently getting the error in prod

```
XSLTParseError: Cannot resolve URI http://...
```

even though it works in development

I'm loading the XSL from my localfiles system like this

```
def transformXml(xml_content)
     xsl = file(os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], 'filename.xslt'),'rb').read()
     xslt_root = etree.XML(xsl)
     transform = etree.XSLT(xslt_root)
     return unicode(transform(xml_content))
```

the xsl file has some includes for external XSL files that are available online like this

```
  <xsl:include href="http://../name1.xslt"/>
  <xsl:include href="http://../name2.xslt"/>
  <xsl:include href="http://../name3.xslt"/>
```

Comment: Please show more code for context. Also: where exactly are you fetching external stylesheets from, your local filesystem?

Comment: the externals xsl files are available online

Comment: Try downloading the included stylesheets to the directory where your Python scripts are. Then, alter the `href` path to a local one. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I couldn't get that to work. For the moment I created a WS in openshift that makes the transformations I need and I get the results from there. I'll keep looking to make it work in appengine